# How do you donate money to Ubuntu?

Tags: canonical, donation

I've been using Ubuntu for months now and I will like to make a donation of $20.00 (its worth $200.00) Seriously,
I checked out the website, and couldn’t
find anywhere to donate. How can I make a donation?

Comment: Maybe this one? https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/contribute